# Can the test set of non-image data be augmented?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have learned the test set of image data can be augmented by a method called `Test Time Augmentation`

and I am wondering after I researched on it if the test set of structured or non-image data can be augmented too.

If it cannot, why does such a method can perform on image data only?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to data augmentation in general, then yes you can apply it to non-image dataset.
Data augmentation means increasing the number of data points.

One of the example is generating synthetic samples for the minority class.

**SMOTE** (Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique) is an oversampling method can be applied to your data through `imblearn` package for python. It works by creating synthetic samples from the minor class instead of creating copies and you can apply it to any numerical data, not only images (actually I've never seen this method applied to images dataset).

You can go [here](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html) and [here](https://beckernick.github.io/oversampling-modeling/) for more detail.